# A telegram bot for get specific data

Tags: text-mining, telegram-bot

I want to create a bot telegram to retrieve some information from another robot or channel
I just wanted a training resource for this

Answer (score 0):

create a userbot wit telethon: https://github.com/LonamiWebs/Telethon/commits?author=Lonami